# 1.9.1 CE Search Box does not work with Umlauts

Tags: search, ce-1.9.1.0

I've a big problem,
I tried to fix that problem in */app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php* 
but it did not work i've added after:

```
$words = Mage::helper('core/string')->splitWords($queryText, true, $query->getMaxQueryWords());
```

Those 2 Arrays:

```
$umlaute = array('Ä','Ö','Ü','ä','ö','ü','ß'); 
$htmlumlaute = array('&Auml;','&Ouml;','&Uuml;','&auml;','&ouml;','&uuml;','&szlig;');
```

and in the foreach line where it searchs the entered word i've added:

```
$like[] = $helper->getCILike('s.data_index', str_replace($umlaute,$htmlumlaute,$word), array('position' => 'any'));
```

So what do i have to do, that the searchbox would work with german Umlauts?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem so far? Normally this is caused by an encoding issue so manually adding string replacements should not be needed here.

Comment: No, the error is still there. I didn't found the issue all settings in magento seemed to be right for me.

Comment: Ok, since we are too experiencing this odd behavior I'll update this post once we've found a solution.